# svn: E170000: Unrecognized URL scheme for httpxxxx

Tags: svn

Looks like the custom built svn doesn't work for http URLs. After searching online, I understood that I need to install neon libraries which I did. After installing neon when i am building the subversion it fails at make. I tried clean and again make, still have issue. Nothing has changed except the installed version of subversion is still existed at /usr/local/subversion. Any idea how to move forward?

OS : RedHat 5

### Version

```
    [root@mercury lib]# svn --version
    svn, version 1.8.0 (r1490375)
       compiled Jul 10 2013, 20:07:32 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

    Copyright (C) 2013 The Apache Software Foundation.
    This software consists of contributions made by many people;
    see the NOTICE file for more information.
    Subversion is open source software, see http://subversion.apache.org/

    The following repository access (RA) modules are available:

    * ra_svn : Module for accessing a repository using the svn network protocol.
      - with Cyrus SASL authentication
      - handles 'svn' scheme
    * ra_local : Module for accessing a repository on local disk.
      - handles 'file' scheme
```

### Configure Subversion

```
[root@mercury subversion-1.8.0]# ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/subversion/ --with-apxs=/usr/local/subversion/bin/apxs --with-apr=/usr/local/subversion/bin/apr-1-config --with-apr-util=/usr/local/subversion/bin/apu-1-config --with-ssl --with-neon=/u01/soft/neon-0.29.6/


.....end lines...

config.status: executing svn_private_config.h.tmp commands
configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-ssl, --with-neon
configure: WARNING: we have configured without BDB filesystem support


You don't seem to have Berkeley DB version 4.0.14 or newer
installed and linked to APR-UTIL.  We have created a Makefile which will build
Subversion without support for the Berkeley DB back-end.  You can find the
latest version of Berkeley DB here:

  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/berkeleydb/downloads/index.html

or explicitly specify --without-berkeley-db to silence this warning.
```

### make

```
[root@mercury subversion-1.8.0]# make
/bin/sh /u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool --tag=CC --silent --mode=compile gcc -std=c89  -DLINUX -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE   -g -O2  -g -O2 -pthread  -I./subversion/include -I./subversion -I/usr/local/subversion//include   -I/usr/local/subversion//include -I/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/sqlite-amalgamation   -o subversion/libsvn_delta/cancel.lo -c subversion/libsvn_delta/cancel.c
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 865: X--tag=CC: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 898: libtool: ignoring unknown tag : command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 865: X--mode=compile: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1031: *** Warning: inferring the mode of operation is deprecated.: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1032: *** Future versions of Libtool will require --mode=MODE be specified.: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: Xgcc: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-std=c89: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-DLINUX: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-D_REENTRANT: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-D_GNU_SOURCE: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-g: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-O2: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-g: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-O2: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-pthread: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-I./subversion/include: No such file or directory
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-I./subversion: No such file or directory
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-I/usr/local/subversion//include: No such file or directory
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-I/usr/local/subversion//include: No such file or directory
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-I/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/sqlite-amalgamation: No such file or directory
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1175: X-c: command not found
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1227: Xsubversion/libsvn_delta/cancel.lo: No such file or directory
/u01/soft/subversion-1.8.0/libtool: line 1232: libtool: compile: cannot determine name of library object from `': command not found
make: *** [subversion/libsvn_delta/cancel.lo] Error 1
```

Comment: subversion 1.8 removed NEON in favor of serf.

Comment: Which OS/Distro have you used?

Comment: OS version is RedHat5

Comment: @Doon From where I can install serf, do I need to rebuild the subversion after installing serf?

Comment: There *should* be a libserf or libserf-devel rpm floating around.  And use you would need to rebuild Subversion and tell it to include serf. But based on your config line I don't see anything "custom",  so @alex_hha answer below would probably work as well.

Comment: I already using the built one and apache is using its module, now if i install rpm it will mess up everything i believe.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You compiled Subversion without serf library used for HTTP/HTTPS protocol:
[http://serf.apache.org/](http://serf.apache.org)

Specify serf library location using `--with-serf` configure option.

Answer (score -1):

You could try to use binary package from http://opensource.wandisco.com/centos/5/svn-1.8/RPMS/x86_64/ if you don't need any specific configuration options